# dynamic annotation for junitbenchmark

Tags: java, dynamic, junit, annotations

to time i write some junitbenchmark tests.
now i want to set warmup and test rounds from a wrapper class.
How to set the BenchmarkOptions annotation from wrapper?

my wrapper class:

```java
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;

public class Wrapper {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        Result result;
        result = junit.run(Test.class);
    }
}
```

my test method in Test.class:

```java
@BenchmarkOptions(benchmarkRounds = 50, warmupRounds = 10)
@Test
public void test1() {
    //something to do
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, your code does not work.

1. You are missing the `BenchmarkRule` in your test.
2. You cannot name a class `Test` when importing an annnotation named `Test`. This will not compile.

Therefore I name that class `BenchmarkTest`.

---

Getting back to your question, you can make use of `BenchmarkOptionsSystemProperties`. In its' documentation is written

> Global settings for benchmarks set through system properties. If IGNORE_ANNOTATION_OPTIONS_PROPERTY is specified, the system properties and defaults will take precedence over the method- and class-level annotations.

This allows you to write a Wrapper as follows

```java
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import com.carrotsearch.junitbenchmarks.BenchmarkOptionsSystemProperties;

public class Wrapper {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty(BenchmarkOptionsSystemProperties.IGNORE_ANNOTATION_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, "true");
        System.setProperty(BenchmarkOptionsSystemProperties.WARMUP_ROUNDS_PROPERTY, "20");
        System.setProperty(BenchmarkOptionsSystemProperties.BENCHMARK_ROUNDS_PROPERTY, "20");

        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        Result result = junit.run(BenchmarkTest.class);
    }
}
```

The according benchmark would look like this

```java
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TestRule;

import com.carrotsearch.junitbenchmarks.BenchmarkOptions;
import com.carrotsearch.junitbenchmarks.BenchmarkOptionsSystemProperties;
import com.carrotsearch.junitbenchmarks.BenchmarkRule;

public class BenchmarkTest {

    @Rule
    public TestRule benchmarkRun = new BenchmarkRule(BenchmarkOptionsSystemProperties.getDefaultConsumers());

    @Test
    @BenchmarkOptions(benchmarkRounds = 1, warmupRounds = 1)
    public void test1() {
        int tmp = 1 + 2;
    }

}
```

When you then execute the mein-method of the Wrapper you get this output, where you can see that the annotation values of 1 have been overridden.

> BenchmarkTest.test1: [measured 20 out of 40 rounds, threads: 1 (sequential)]
>    round: 0.00 [+- 0.00], round.block: 0.00 [+- 0.00], round.gc: 0.00 [+- 0.00], GC.calls: 0, GC.time: 0.00, time.total: 0.01, time.warmup: 0.00, time.bench: 0.00